# Para que serve a propriedade UseShellExecute?

Tags: c#, .net, processo

Desenvolvendo uma aplicação em c# me deparei com a propriedade `UseShellExecute` no seguinte trecho de código:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
```

Qual a finalidade dela? Li que ela indica se o *shell* do SO deve ser usado ou não e continuei sem entender, qual o impacto na aplicação caso ela seja `true`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Poucas vezes é interessante o seu uso, tem mais desvantagens que vantagens.

Como ele é usado como se fosse um *shell* mesmo ele tem as características de como você estivesse usando o `cmd.exe` do Windows ou outro *shell* padrão do sistema operacional.

Ele acessa o o que está no `PATH`, executa *scripts* batch, e usa a associação de certos nomes com aplicações específicas. De forma geral é um ganho desnecessário em quase todas situações já que é mais uma conveniência. Em geral é melhor ser específico e direto no que está chamando, até para evitar executar o que você não tem um controle maior.

Ele tem dificuldades também. A segurança é limitada e fica comprometida. Não é possível redirecionar o resultado para algum *stream*.

Nesse exemplo só vejo desvantagens e botar `true`.

A [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Diagnostics_ProcessStartInfo_UseShellExecute) é sua amiga.

Answer (score 2):

Essa propriedade **`UseShellExecute`** está relacionada com o uso da função `ShellExecute` existente no Windows ou seja, se você marcar como `true` a classe `Process` usará a função `ShellExecute`, senão, usará a `CreateProcess`.

### CreateProcess

Este é seu caso e será utilizado a função `CreateProcess`, é uma maneira muito mais precisa de iniciar um processo - ele não pesquisa o caminho, e permitirá você redirecionar a entrada ou saída padrão do processo filho.
Não vai funcionar quando tentar abrir arquivos como será explicado no `ShellExecute`.

Você deve definir `UseShellExecute` como `false` quando:

- Deseja simplesmente abrir um programa;

### ShellExecute

A função `ShellExecute` é usada para abrir um arquivo específico (até mesmo um programa) - como quando digitamos algo no comando Executar do Windows, por exemplo quando desejamos:

- Abrir documentos onde as extensões já foram associadas a um programa - simplesmente digitamos c:\teste\fat.docx que o Windows se encarregará de abrir o programa WinWord.
- Executar arquivos em lote - como no `cmd.exe`;
- Executar qualquer comando no PATH;

Use quando você deseja abrir documentos, urls ou arquivos em lote etc... em vez de ter que explicitamente passar o caminho de onde o programa foi instalado.